# Where is the intercept term in type II Anova function from the car package?

Tags: r, anova, r-car

I have constructed a simple linear model and performed both a Type II & III analysis of variance using the `Anova()` function from the `car` package. In the output, the Type III `Anova` includes an intercept, whereas no intercept is included in the Type II `Anova`.

Type II

```
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: Zero.Tillage
           Sum Sq   Df F value   Pr(>F)   
Gender      0.732    1   9.723 0.001844 **
Residuals 159.856 2123                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Type III

```
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: Zero.Tillage
             Sum Sq   Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)   2.037    1  27.055 2.167e-07 ***
Gender        0.732    1   9.723  0.001844 ** 
Residuals   159.856 2123                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

What is the reasoning behind this? How do I determine if the model intercept is significant if I want to use a Type II test?